# c++ error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct st_list LIST’

Tags: mysql, list, ocr, declaration, tesseract

first of all:
I already read the [Avoiding conflicting declaration errors in typedef c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865744/avoiding-conflicting-declaration-errors-in-typedef-c) post and the answer doesnt solve my problem :-(

Im working on a project where I need tesseract OCR and mysql which both define a LIST type in their headers.

here you is the error message:

```
Building file: ../src/CardRecognitionSystem.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/leptonica -I/usr/local/include/tesseract -I/usr/local/include -O2 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fno-strict-aliasing   -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/CardRecognitionSystem.d" -MT"src/CardRecognitionSystem.d" -o "src/CardRecognitionSystem.o" "../src/CardRecognitionSystem.cpp"
In file included from /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:75:0,
                 from ../src/CardRepoController.h:18,
                 from ../src/CardRecognitionSystem.h:24,
                 from ../src/CardRecognitionSystem.cpp:10:
/usr/include/mysql/my_list.h:26:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct st_list LIST’
 } LIST;
   ^
In file included from ../src/OCRStringResolver.h:17:0,
                 from ../src/CardNameResolver.h:11,
                 from ../src/CardRecognitionSystem.h:22,
                 from ../src/CardRecognitionSystem.cpp:10:
/usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:61:19: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct list_rec* LIST’
 typedef list_rec *LIST
```

;

I included the mysql.h header ONLY in CardRepoController.h and the tesseract headers in other files but I need all of them in CardRecognitionSystem.h.
And there I think lays the problem..

Do you have any ideas how to use both libs beside each other?

Comment: Using the namespace qualifiers should solve the problem. You're probably using: "using namespace cv::tesseract;" (or something similar, I don't remember now) that will import all names and cause the name collision

Comment: hmm no, im not even using namespace std; :(

Comment: Ok just a wide guess.. :D post some code, could be useful